# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.StreamUtils in GAE

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

My project don't work in GAE on global side, but it work correctly in local GAE server.
Logs from global server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.StreamUtils
```

I see this exception when i call `getLogin()` method, but methos `setUserINN()` work is correctly.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getSalesInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public @ResponseBody String getLogin(){
        MasterAccountInfo msi = dataMethods.getMasterAccountInfo();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(msi);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "failed transform";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/setuserINN", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String setUserINN(@RequestParam("INN") String INN){
        Principal pr = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String str = pr.getName();
        dataMethods.changeUserInfo(str, INN);
        return "redirect:/myaccount";
    }
}
```

I have no idea about this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamUtils was added in Spring 3.2.2.  You'll need to upgrade to at least that version of Spring for it to work.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how ant was compiled `WAR` in local machine but

`org.springframework.util.StreamUtils` exist only in `spring-core-4.0.jar` I used 3.1.1 version without this package.

I am insert library v4.0 in WAR and all is work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your spring version to at least(4.2.1.RELEASE) or latest version for it to work.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.